# Starting mongodb cluster

Tags: mongodb

I'm starting 3 mongod processes on 3 different machines and try to run the mongos process on the another machine that runs also the application server.

I'm getting this message:

```
~$ mongos --configdb mongo1:27017,mongo2:27017,mongo3:27017
Mon Sep 24 10:34:05 mongos db version v2.0.4, pdfile version 4.5 starting (--help for usage)
Mon Sep 24 10:34:05 git version: nogitversion
Mon Sep 24 10:34:05 build info: Linux yellow 2.6.24-29-server #1 SMP Tue Oct 11 15:57:27 UTC 2011 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_46_1
Mon Sep 24 10:34:09 ERROR: config servers mongo1:27017 and mongo2:27017 differconfig servers mongo1:27017 and mongo2:27017 differconfig servers mongo1:27017 and mongo2:27017 differconfig servers mongo1:27017 and mongo2:27017 differconfig servers not in sync! config servers mongo1:27017 and mongo2:27017 differ
chunks: "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"  EOO
EOO EOO
configServer startup check failed
```

Comment: are you sure, that the config servers are running on port 27017? Normally this is 27019.

Comment: Mon Sep 24 08:33:29 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've deleted `mongod.lock` from all config servers and restarted mongod. 
That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways it can be done,

1) clear the data folder and restart the server, it will start as usual without any error,

2) delete the mongod lock file and Use the --repair option.